# reseeding patchy lawn

Tags: lawn, repair

I pulled out some weeds and tried to reseed both in the front and back yard, the back seeds sprouted and grew but the front yard just will not germinate.  I seeded, watered and used the same grass seed from the same bag - why won't the front yard germinate?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the growing conditions are different - its sunnnier, or more shady, or drier, more exposed to wind, etc. Whatever the difference, you probably just need to give more care to the seed there, such as ensuring the seed bed is kept moist. If its very shady, then try using a seed mix designed for shady areas.